# How many vertices should we discard so that the remaining partial graph is Eulerian

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Let V be an undirected graph with 100 nodes and  4950 edges.
How many edges should we delete so that the remaining partial graph is Eulerian ? And what's the reasoning ?

Comment: What is the difference between a vertex and a node? Also necessary and sufficient conditions are know for when a graph is Eulerian and they depend on the degree of each vertex. No information on degree is given.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I rectified my mistake , those are absolutely all the details we've been given.This problem must have a solution that only implies the details we've been provided with,otherwise, it wouldn't be in my textbook.

Comment: @JMac31 No difference between a vertex and a node

Comment: @John Fernley I know. That comment was for the original version of the question in which the graph had 100 nodes and 4950 vertices. But I see everything has been revised and resolved now. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple graph on $100$ vertices has at most $\binom{100}{2} = 4950$ edges. So the graph in question is the complete graph on 100 vertices, $K_{100}$. Each vertex of $K_{100}$ has degree $99$, so $K_{100}$ is not Eulerian. If you delete $1$ vertex from $K_{100}$, you obtain $K_{99}$, each vertex of which has degree $98$, and thus is Eulerian. So $1$ vertex is both necessary and sufficient.

Edit: Now that you mean that you want to delete edges, not vertices, $K_{100}$ has $100$ vertices of odd degree. So we must delete at least $1$ edge incident with each vertex in order to make the graph Eulerian. Since each edge is incident with $2$ vertices, this means we must delete at least $50$ edges. If you delete perfect matching in $K_{100}$, all remaining vertices will have degree $98$, and will thus be Eulerian. So $50$ edges is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Sorry , Mr. @Perry Iverson , I meant edges instead of vertices(it's kinda late here and I'm awfully sleepy) , I'm terribly sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Victor I modified my answer to include the solution for edges.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving such a detailed solution !